# How can I put this in a loop, tried using a while loop at the beginning but I would get the wrong output

Tags: python, loops

- Program to simulate a roll of two six-sided dices, if both score the same number (example:(6,6)) equals a double.
- I'd like the user to be able to go again after they rolled the dice and number of doubles have been shown.

Thanks in advance.

```
import random

user_input= int(input("How many times would you like to roll the dice?"))

Dice_1 = [random.randint(1,6) for x in range(user_input)]
Dice_2 = [random.randint(1,6) for x in range(user_input)]

count = 0
for a,b in zip(Dice_1,Dice_2):
    if((a)) == ((b)):
        print("double")
        count += 1
    else:
        print((a,b))

print(f'\nYou have scored {count} doubles! out of {user_input}')
```

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure on your first attempt, but I would say it would be great to see what you tried even if it failed :)

Using a while loop is the easiest and most convenient way to do it. e.g.

```py
import random

while user_input := int(input("How many times would you like to roll the dice?")) :
    Dice_1 = ...
    ... # roll dice, blah blah
```

would do what you want. Inputting 0 will break the while loop (since `0` is considered false in python, i.e. `while 0` -> `while False` and any other integers than 0 is considered true). Note that it used walrus operator `:=` instead of `=`

Without the walrus operator, the above is similar with below:

```py
user_input = int(input("How many times would you like to roll the dice?"))

while user_input != 0:
  ... # roll dice, blah blah
  
  #then ask again if they want to roll again
  user_input = int(input("How many times would you like to roll the dice?")
```

the `:=` walrus operator is just a way to make it more readable (it computes the resulting value of `:= int(input("How many times would you like to roll the dice?"))` and assign it to `user_input`).